# WPF Global hotkey not registering

Tags: c#, wpf

I have code which should detect when Shift + Numpad1 is pressed in my application. The hotkey is successfully registered, but the if statement within my WndProc function never triggers (i.e. 'Hotkey pressed' message box is never shown). The relevant code is attached below

```
        private GlobalHotkey ghk;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ghk = new GlobalHotkey(Constants.SHIFT, Keys.NumPad1, new WindowInteropHelper(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle);
            if (!ghk.Register())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hotkey Failed to register");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hotkey Registered");
            }
            

            NotifyIcon icon = new NotifyIcon();
            icon.Icon = new Icon("MainIcon.ico");
            icon.Visible = true;
            icon.DoubleClick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs args) {
                Activate();
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            };

            icon.ContextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu(new MenuItem[] { 
                new MenuItem("Quit", (object s, EventArgs e) => {
                        Close();
                    }) 
            });
            
        }

        protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
                Hide();

            base.OnStateChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
            source.AddHook(WndProc);
        }

        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            textBox.Text = msg.ToString();
            if (msg == Constants.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID)
            {
                HandleHotkey();
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        private void HandleHotkey()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("HotkeyPressed");
            Activate();
        }
```

In the code `Constants.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID`= 0x0312

Global hotkey class:

```
public class GlobalHotkey
    {
        private int modifier;
        private int key;
        private IntPtr hWnd;
        private int id;

        public GlobalHotkey(int modifier, Keys key, IntPtr handle)
        {
            this.modifier = modifier;
            this.key = (int)key;
            this.hWnd = handle;
            this.id = this.GetHashCode();
        }

        public bool Register()
        {
            return RegisterHotKey(hWnd, id, modifier, key);
        }

        public bool Unregister()
        {
            return UnregisterHotKey(hWnd, id);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return modifier ^ key ^ hWnd.ToInt32();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
    }
```

Comment: did you try debugging? Put a break-point here `if (msg == Constants.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID)` and see whats happening

Comment: I have, messages are being sent but they never equal 0x0312 even when I press the correct key combination.

Comment: you are trying to activate a thing when 2 buttons are pressed. This is not the usual way. Events exist for each button. Not for the combinations of the buttons. 2 different events for 2 buttons might be fired.

Comment: The code also does not work when I apply no modifier (so when only Numpad 1 is pressed)

Comment: You're registering the HotKey too soon. Do that in `OnSourceInitialized` (after `base.OnSourceInitialized(e);`), not in the Window constructor. Are you referencing System.Windows.Forms (the `Keys` thing)?

Comment: BTW, the ID you're using is not that good. Use just `0x100` as the base HotKey ID and increment by 1 for each new HotKey you add (HotKeys are already tied to `hWnd` you're passing to the function). Remember to call `UnregisterHotKey()` in `OnClosing`. -- `Constants.SHIFT = 4`, right?

Comment: Thanks, moving it to OnSourceInitialised and changing the hotkey to not use the numpad worked! I'm already calling `UnregisterHotKey()` in `OnClosing()`

Comment: Yep, the NumPad is tricky (OEM stuff). You can register, e.g., `Keys.End` (same keyboard key as `Keys.NumPad1`), but Num Lock must be off. Things like this.

Comment: (sorry, I had to go *elsewhere*)... But, of course, you can register `ALT+NumPad1` and `Control+NumPad1` or `ALT+Control+NumPad1`. Not `SHIFT+NumPad1` or `ALT+SHIFT+NumPad1`. So, no `SHIFT`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you don't need to reference System.Windows.Form to get Keys you can pass to a Win32 API. You can use `var vk = KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(Key)` to convert an `Input.Key` to a Virtual Key. You can also use the `ModifierKeys` enumeration to handle `ALT`, `SHIFT` etc. modifiers (these values match the Win32 API values). Except `NoRepeat = 0x4000`.